# Prestashop - How to migrate an existing database to a new prestashop project?

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm a junior developper still studying (half company, half school) in a small company.

Our host was OVH and recently the server burned destroying all of our files and also the backup because it seems like it was located close to our production server. The company is hiring an external developper that handle the database, updates of modules... However they don't have any local server to store internal backups. So the company lost everything except a SQL file that I have on my computer which could be used to rebuild a new website.

The issue is that I know only but a little about prestashop is it possible to build a new project using the old MySQL file ? I tried by creating a LAMP using PHP 5.6. I imported the SQL into a database and I created a brand new prestashop 1.6.1.23. The problem is that I can't link the database to new project or it throw me a 500 error without displaying any error (the debug mode is set to True).

**How could I manage to link an existing prestashop database to a new prestashop ?**

Comment: Go to file structure config->settings.inc.php. In this file, change DB fields values like hostname, user and password as per requirement.

Comment: I did change however it throws me a 500 error without displaying any error

Comment: Did you set debug mode to true in define.inc.php file.

Comment: yes I did set it to true

Comment: Then remove all cache in cache folder and change shop_url table as per your project name.

Comment: this issue is resolved thanks, however I'm now getting a depreciation error about using `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` I moved to a php 5.6 but I think this is still too recent for a prestashop 1.6.1.23 do you have any clue ?

Comment: Check this link to see PHP version requirement for every prestashop version - https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/